# How can i access javaScript variable in current jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#comboBox1").change(function() {
        var text2 = $(this).children(':selected').text();  
    var value2 = $(this).val();  
      });
    });
</script>

<body>
<form>
<select id="comboBox1">
  <option value="val1">opt1</option>
  <option value="val2">opt2</option>
</select>
```

//Here i have class called MyUtill that has method findArray with require 1 parameter
// i need to pass combo selected value from the javascript variable value2 so how can i get that variable in my scriptlate

```
<%
Map<String,String> myMap = MyUtil.findArray(variable);   // variable require javascript value2 variable so how can i get 
%>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: In here JS is client-side and JSP are generated by server, there is no way 'server' to explain anything about page after rendering, except using ajax or forms.

Comment: i does not want to submit page...
so there is any way of ajax that you know so please tell me...

Comment: If you don’t know how to use AJAX, then please do some research on this topic.